# Some properties of the determinant and the trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, trace

Could anyone please explain steps $\color{red}{(1)}$ and $\color{blue}{(2)}$? :)

---

[image]

---

A reference to the background of these guys would also be helpful.

Comment: Some odd notation here: what is $S^n_{++}$? And where does this extract come from?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the source? Material looks interesting

Comment: Convex Optimization by prof.Boyd. The notation mentioned designates Symmetric Matrix, which is Positive Definite. All the answers were clear and helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $X=I+tvv^T$, $YX = Y + tYvv^T = Y + t\lambda vv^T$. Trace is linear, so
$$ \operatorname{tr}{(YX)} = \operatorname{tr}{(Y+t\lambda vv^T)} = \operatorname{tr}{Y} + t\lambda \operatorname{tr}{(vv^T)}. $$
Trace is also cyclic, in that $\operatorname{tr}{(AB)}=\operatorname{tr}{(BA)}$, so $\operatorname{tr}{(vv^T)} = \operatorname{tr}{(v^Tv)} = \operatorname{tr}{(\lVert v \rVert_2^2)} = 1$ since this is just a scalar, and the red expression follows.

For the determinant, $\det{(I+tvv^T)}$, since a determinant is invariant under change-of-basis, we can evaluate it using an orthonormal basis where $v$ is the first vector. Then the matrix of $I+tvv^T$ is diagonal with elements $ 1+t , 1,1, \dotsc $, which has determinant $(1+t) \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \dotsb = 1+t$, which is the blue expression.

Comment: I have a question. For {  YX=Y+tYvvT=Y+tλvvT }, how did Y suddenly turned into eigenvalue λ (a scalar)? (And then you pull this out of the trace operator.

Comment: It's using that $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, so $Tv=\lambda v$ is the replacement made. And $\operatorname{tr}{(A+B)}=\operatorname{tr}{A}+\operatorname{tr}{B}$ (which is one consequence of being linear) is then applied.

Answer (score 1):

Step $\color{blue}{\boxed{2}}$ uses the [Weinstein-Aronszajn determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity),

$$\det \left( \,\mathrm I + t \, \mathrm v \mathrm v^\top \right)  = \det \left( 1 + t \, \mathrm v^\top \mathrm v \right) = 1 + t \, \| \mathrm v \|_2^2 = \color{blue}{1 + t}$$

because $\| \mathrm v \|_2 = 1$.

Comment: Obviously helpful. Thanks.

I have selected the another one only because I cannot choose multiple answers!

Comment: I have additional question. Why do we assume Y is symmetric?

Comment: When using positive / negative definiteness, symmetry is assumed. A non-symmetric matrix can have positive eigenvalues and not be positive definite.